# How to implement dimension agnostic matrix-vector multiplication in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, matrix-multiplication, typechecking, existential-type

I defined a matrix type with existentially hidden dimensions, so I could form lists of arbitrarily sized matrices:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Sized as VS
import           Data.Vector.Sized (Vector)

-- | A matrix with existentially hidden dimensions.
data Mat :: * -> * where
  Mat :: (Vector m :.: Vector n) a -> Mat a
```

But, now, I can't figure out how to define my matrix-vector multiplication function in a way that type checks.
Trying this:

```
| Matrix-vector multiplication for existentially typed matrices.
(^*^)
  :: (KnownNat m, KnownNat n, Num a)
  => Mat a       -- ^ transform matrix
  -> Vector n a  -- ^ input vector
  -> Vector m a
Mat (Comp1 mat) ^*^ v = VS.map (dot v) mat

dot :: (KnownNat n, Num a) => Vector n a -> Vector n a -> a
u `dot` v = VS.sum $ VS.zipWith (*) u v
```

results in:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘m1’ with ‘m’
  ‘m1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Mat :: forall a (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat).
             (:.:) (Vector m) (Vector n) a -> Mat a,
    in an equation for ‘^*^’
    at src/RL/MulES.hs:89:1-15
  ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (^*^) :: forall (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat) a.
               (KnownNat m, KnownNat n) =>
               Mat a -> Vector n a -> Vector m a
    at src/RL/MulES.hs:(84,1)-(88,15)
  Expected type: Vector m a
    Actual type: Vector m1 a
• In the expression: VS.map (dot v) mat
  In an equation for ‘^*^’:
      Mat (Comp1 mat) ^*^ v = VS.map (dot v) mat
• Relevant bindings include
    mat :: Vector m1 (Vector n8 a) (bound at src/RL/MulES.hs:89:12)
    (^*^) :: Mat a -> Vector n a -> Vector m a
      (bound at src/RL/MulES.hs:89:17)
   |
89 | Mat (Comp1 mat) ^*^ v = VS.map (dot v) mat
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I have a matrix, but won't tell you its dimensions. How would you multiply it by a vector of length 5? I'd argue that this is harder than defining multiplication between a 12x34 matrix and a 5-vector, since in this case we also know the dimensions. But the latter is impossible to reasonably define, hence the former is as well.

Answer (score 2):

First let me remark that I find this whole idea quite dubious: why do you bother fixing dimensions through the type system if you then throw it away again with the existential wrapper?

Since you don't know the domain dimension of that linear mapping, the only vector you can apply it to is one that *can have any dimension on demand*. That's pretty crazy, but it can be expressed in Haskell using `-XRank2Types`. Also you don't know the codomain dimension, so the result must again be existentially wrapped. The existential wrappers must contain a `KnownNat` constraint, else you won't be able to do anything with the vectors at all. Like

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, Rank2Types, UnicodeSyntax #-}

-- | This is really just a pretentious replacement for Data.Vector.Vector
data Array :: * -> * where
  Array :: KnownNat n => Vector n a -> Mat a

data Mat :: * -> * where
  Mat :: (KnownNat n, KnownNat m) => (Vector m :.: Vector n) a -> Mat a

lapply :: Num a => Mat a -> (∀ n . KnownNat n => Vector n a) -> Array a
lapply (Mat m) v = Array $ VS.map (dot v) mat
```

Will this be useful for anything? Not sure. You could actually create such a length-agnostic vector if what you really want to express is a *continuous function* that's PCM-sampled on a uniform grid (what the Matlab folks use all day, instead of having proper function types...). The sampling would automatically be adjusted to whatever resolution the matrix demands.

But, at runtime this just means your input “vector” is actually a function that takes a resolution-argument. There's not much the whole type-level-number foo buys you here.

IMO, when you find yourself dealing with such “variable length vectors” it's usually a sign that you're really working in an *infinite-dimensional vector space*, like usually such a function space. (The most widely-used such space is the [*L*<sup>2</sup> Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).) This can't really be expressed with any array-based approach, but it can be expressed if you ditch the *dimension/element* decomposition and instead use vector spaces *as a typeclass*. [Conal Elliott's package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) for this has been around for a long time now; it may seem a bit dated but is actually quite practically useful still. I spend some effort building upon it [a proper category of linear maps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.4.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html), haven't really gotten to the point of making it fully usable for infinite-dimensional spaces though.